# At practice vs of practice

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Suppose I want to know how many hours are needed to be able to do it on my own, like for instance, driving a car.

> How many years of/at practice do I need to became a basic user?

In the quoted sentence which one preposition would you use?

If both are acceptable, in which context would one fit better than another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that sentence you need *of*.

Comment: Would you use "How many years have you been *at* practice?" in place of "How many years have you been practicing?"

Comment: @Gaffi, **at** practice normally means "engaged in a session of practice". It most often implies practicing with others: *He's at football practice* or *band practice*. If the subject is working alone, *He's practicing* would be more usual, but *He's been at practice for two hours* wouldn't raise eyebrows.

Comment: As @StoneyB says.